# Django/Python: How to call function from parent class within child class?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I currently have two classes, `Main` and `Calculator`. `Main` has multiple functions within it. I am trying to call the functions within main from within my calculator class. How do I do it?

Here is my current view...

```
class Main(object):
    template = ""
    favorite_number = None
    least_favorite_number = None

    def add (self, request, a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(self, request, a, b):
        return a - b

    def multiply(self, request, a, b):
        return a * b

    def divide(self, request, a, b):
        return a / b

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'inherit/index.html')

class Calculator(Main, View):
    template = 'calculator/index.html'
    favorite_number = 20
    least_favorite_number = 2

print self.add(request, favorite_number, least_favorite_number)
```

Comment: Have you tried just calling them?

Comment: @IanAuld Yes. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine, except for the fact that the `print` statement isn't indented properly, and therefore is not part of `Calculator()` There's also no point of adding `self` and `request` to the `Main` methods.

views.py

```
class Main(object):
    template = ""
    favorite_number = None
    least_favorite_number = None

    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(a, b):
        return a - b

    def multiply(a, b):
        return a * b

    def divide(a, b):
        return a / b

class Calculator(Main, View):
    template = 'calculator/index.html'
    favorite_number = 20
    least_favorite_number = 2

    def get(self, request):
        print self.add(self.favorite_number, self.least_favorite_number)
        return render(request, self.template, {})
```

Keep in mind that in order for you to see the `print` statement in your console, you have to actually be looking at the view. So wire in the `Calculator` view into urls.py, navigate to the page, and you should be able to see if the `print` statement is working in the console.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. So far, I am getting the add function to print the results of the function into the terminal, but I am getting flagged with this error when I refresh the page `The view apps.inherit.views.Calculator didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: NVM, I figured it out. Thanks a bunch man, you really helped me out tonight!